# Unknown types name UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibezierpath

I plan to make a QRBar scanner, I found a source called "IOS7_BarcodeScanner" which implement the any types of scanner to be used. I try the demo sources, and it works like a charm. But when I comes to creating my own project, and implement it. Unknown types name UIBezierPath, even I copy and paste exactly the files from demo source. It doesn't work. I have import the frameworks accordingly.

**Barcode.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import AVFoundation;

@interface Barcode : NSObject 


+ (Barcode * )processMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject*) code;
- (NSString *) getBarcodeType;
- (NSString *) getBarcodeData;
- (void) printBarcodeData;
@end
```

**Barcode.m**

```
#import "Barcode.h"

@interface Barcode()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *cornersPath;
@end

@implementation Barcode

@end
```

**Error**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *cornersPath;
```

**Message**

> Unknown type name 'UIBezierPath'
>   Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import UIKit framework

Objective-C :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> OR @import UIKit;
```

Swift

```
   import UIKit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the top of your .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```